# android OnClickListener sharedPreferences

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```java
/*1*/final OnClickListener clearTagsButtonListener = new OnClickListenener()
    {
        @Override
        /*2*/public void onClick (View v)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setPositiveButton
            /*a*/(R.string.erase, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Button) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        clearButtons();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
                        preferencesEditor.clear();
                        preferencesEditor.apply();

                    }
                });

        };

    };
```

the errors that eclipse displays are:

1. Multiple markers at this line
       - OnClickListenener cannot be resolved to a type
       - Type mismatch: cannot convert from new OnClickListenener(){} to    DialogInterface.OnClickListener
2. Multiple markers at this line
       - The method onClick(View) of type new OnClickListenener(){} must override or implement a supertype      method
       - Method breakpoint:MainActivity [entry] - onClick(View)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to import this :

```
android.view.View.OnClickListener
```

look this code :

```
 final android.view.View.OnClickListener clearTagsButtonListener = new android.view.View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        /*2*/public void onClick (View v)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setPositiveButton
            /*a*/(R.string.erase, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Button) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        clearButtons();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savedSearches.edit();
                        preferencesEditor.clear();
                        preferencesEditor.apply();

                    }
                });

        };

    };
```